# best solution for importing non-typescript npm modules

Tags: angular, systemjs, typescript1.6

with ES6 using traceur and SystemJS this form is correct:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

for Typescript it is not enough - I get error `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'lodash'` So, I install 'lodash.d.ts' :

```
/// <reference path="lodash/lodash.d.ts" />
import _ from 'lodash';
```

Now, I get: `Module '"lodash"' has no default export.` from Typescript compiler

So, I try 'node style':

```
/// <reference path="lodash/lodash.d.ts" />
let _ = require('lodash');
```

I get: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: require is not a function` in browser

Finally:

```
import _ = require('lodash');
```

and it works but it's 'old form' not proper ES6.

Is there a single, proper way to use ES6 style Typescript import for non-typescript modules?

(Typescript 1.6.2)

Comment: I've added the angular2 tag since this approach is common to Angular2 also

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `import * as _ from 'lodash';`

Comment: I've tried:  "import * as _ from './../node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash';" and
"import * as _ from 'lodash';" and still get error that the module cannot be found.

Comment: @brando did you solve this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @jwaern unfortunately, I have not solved this.  the problem is that, while you can get lodash broken down into modules, there is no typescript definition file for each module, so you cant reference it from your import statement.  Hopefully lodash will update the definitions soon

Answer (score 1):

if you import lodash as node_module, you might need to do it as
declare var _: any;

if you wanna do import * as _ from 'lodash', then import loadash thru TypeScript Definition manager (tsd). in terminal, do it as

tsd install lodash --save